# Match everything between word and punctuation at end of line

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to figure out some regex in Javascript, I want to match everything between a word and the end of the line (or punctuation at the end of the line) but can't seem to get it to work correctly. This is what I have so far:

```
/^([\w\d]+)\s(is|are)\s([^\n\r.!?]+)/i
```

Want to return X, is/are, and Y in all situations below:

- X is/are Y!
- X is/are Y?
- X is/are Y.
- X is/are Y

And if that was it, I would just capture all characters that aren't .!?
But sentence structure in reality sometimes ends up being:

```
User is test@example.com!!!
```

Which doesn't work for the with the . in the email so I came up with this:

```
/^([\w\d]+)\s(is|are)\s(.*)[\.\!\?]*$/i
```

But the (.*) captures everything including the punctuation marks at the end. So instead of returning:

```
['User', 'is', 'test@example.com']
```

I get

```
['User', 'is', 'text@example.com!!!']
```

What am I missing here? How do I get it to ignore punctuation marks but ONLY if they're at the end of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your capturing group lazy by changing it to `(.*?)`:

```
> 'User is test@example.com!!!'.match(/^([\w\d]+)\s(is|are)\s(.*)[\.\!\?]*$/i).slice(1)
["User", "is", "test@example.com!!!"]
> 'User is test@example.com!!!'.match(/^([\w\d]+)\s(is|are)\s(.*?)[\.\!\?]*$/i).slice(1)
["User", "is", "test@example.com"]
```

The issue arises because in `(.*)[\.\!\?]*`, the second half can always be empty and the first half can greedily consume everything. If you use `(.*?)`, the capturing group consumes as little as possible.